# Why aren't my matrices adding?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

When I add the matrices, my added matrix output is just zeroes instead of the added numbers. My instructor says the problem may be that I passed the sum as a double pointer instead of a triple pointer to update it, but I don't know how to fix it. What do I do so the matrix numbers sums come out instead of zeroes?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>



int** make_matrixA(int num_rows, int num_cols){
int** matrixA;
int row, col;
int userNum;


    matrixA = (int**)malloc(num_rows * sizeof(int*));
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    matrixA[row] = (int*)malloc(num_cols * sizeof(int));
}
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    for(col = 0; col < num_cols; ++col){
        scanf("%d", &userNum);
    }
}
return matrixA;
}

int** make_matrixB(int num_rows, int num_cols){
int** matrixB;
int row, col;
int userNum;


    matrixB = (int**)malloc(num_rows * sizeof(int*));
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    matrixB[row] = (int*)malloc(num_cols * sizeof(int));
}
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    for(col = 0; col < num_cols; ++col){
        scanf("%d", &userNum);
    }
}
return matrixB;
}

int** make_matrixC(int num_rows, int num_cols){
int** matrixC;
int row;


    matrixC = (int**)malloc(num_rows * sizeof(int*));
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    matrixC[row] = (int*)malloc(num_cols * sizeof(int));
}
return matrixC;
}


int** add_matrix(int num_rows, int num_cols, int** matrixA, int** matrixB, int** matrixC){
int row, col;

for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    for(col = 0; col < num_cols; ++col){
        matrixC[row][col] = matrixA[row][col] + matrixB[row][col];
    }
}
return matrixC;
}

void print_matrix(int num_rows, int num_cols,int** matrixA, int** matrixB, int** matrixC){
int row, col;

printf("A + B = \n");
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    for(col = 0; col < num_cols; ++col){
        matrixC[row][col] = matrixA[row][col] + matrixB[row][col];
        printf("%d ", matrixC[row][col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

void delete_matrixA(int num_rows, int** matrixA){
int row;
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    free(matrixA[row]);
}
free(matrixA);
}

void delete_matrixB(int num_rows, int** matrixB){
int row;
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    free(matrixB[row]);
}
free(matrixB);
}

void delete_matrixC(int num_rows, int** matrixC){
int row;
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    free(matrixC[row]);
}
free(matrixC);
}

int main(){
int num_rows, num_cols;
int** matrixA;
int** matrixB;
int** matrixC;  

//get input
printf("Please enter the number of rows: ");
scanf("%d", &num_rows);
printf("Please enter the number of columns: ");
scanf("%d", &num_cols);     

//make matrix A
printf("Enter Matrix A\n");
matrixA = make_matrixA(num_rows, num_cols);

//make matrix B
printf("Enter Matrix B\n");
matrixB = make_matrixB(num_rows, num_cols);

//add the matrices
matrixC = make_matrixC(num_rows, num_cols);
matrixC = add_matrix(num_rows, num_cols, matrixA, matrixB, matrixC);

//print the matrix
print_matrix(num_rows, num_cols, matrixA, matrixB, matrixC);

//delete the matrices
delete_matrixA(num_rows, matrixA);
delete_matrixB(num_rows, matrixB);
delete_matrixC(num_rows, matrixC);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just comments: why do you have `make_matrixA` and `make_matrixB` when the code is identical? Why return anything from `add_matrix` when you already give in the `matrixC` which will have the values? Why does `print_matrix` also calculate sums and not just print? As for the problem, what did you learn by debugging the `add_matrix` function?

Comment: Your instructor should have told you to use 2D arrays aka matrices and that being a three-star C programmer is not a compliment. Sheds a bad light on her. There is nothing like a 2D array/matrix, nor which can hold one in your code.

Comment: You should really try to generalize your functions a bit more... for example, one function to allocate a matrix, one function to enter values, etc.  Also, you don't need to pass *all* the matrices to every function, just the one(s) that function will use.  And, why are you adding the matrices inside your print function when you've already added them in your adding function?

Answer (score 2):

Your `make_matrix()` functions are not good. The code to read numbers

```
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    for(col = 0; col < num_cols; ++col){
        scanf("%d", &userNum);
    }
}
```

You should do

```
for(row = 0; row < num_rows; ++row){
    for(col = 0; col < num_cols; ++col){
        scanf("%d", &matrixA[row][col]); //use matrix to store number
    }
}
```

Change your functions appropriately to use correct variables.
without this your code does not store values in matrix and adds up random numbers that are in matrices.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just this change made it work perfectly!